# Building a Cocoapods Module error [ARC] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm quiet new at iOS development, this is my first question at SO. At my company we're trying to convert our app in a Cocoapods module to help as to create diferent apps with similiar functionalities. So far we achive to compile the POD module, but when we're trying to import the classes from the module at the workspace's Example attached we get a "Could not build module 'ProjectCore'

```
#import <ProjectCore/myProjectCoreClass.h>
```

No getting more details where the building is failing. Am I missing something? There is any way to know where the building process is failing?

Thanks.

After checking the guide deeply and trying the lint check for the building with:

```
pod lib lint --verbose --allow-warnings
```

My project use ARC in only some modules, so the podspec is like this.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'ProjectCore'
s.version          = '0.1.3'
s.summary          = 'A short description of ProjectCore.'


s.description      = 'This is our core a git with cocoapods - ProjectCore.'

s.homepage         = 'https://bitbucket.org/projectcore/ios_projectcore'
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'Comapny' => 'info@company.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://bitbucket.org/projectcore/ios_projectcore.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'


s.frameworks = 'CoreData', 'SystemConfiguration', 'Accelerate', 'CoreGraphics', 'CoreLocation', 'CoreText', 'GLKit', 'ImageIO', 'OpenGLES', 'QuartzCore', 'UIKit', 'AdSupport', "GoogleMapsCore", "GoogleMapsBase", "GoogleMaps", "Crashlytics", "Fabric"
s.library = 'z', 'c++', 'xml2'
s.vendored_frameworks   = "StaticLibraries/GoogleMapsServices/GoogleMaps.framework", "StaticLibraries/GoogleMapsServices/GoogleMapsBase.framework", "StaticLibraries/GoogleMapsServices/GoogleMapsCore.framework", 'StaticLibraries/FabricCrashlytics/Crashlytics.framework', 'StaticLibraries/FabricCrashlytics/Fabric.framework'
s.vendored_libraries = 'StaticLibraries/GoogleAnalyticsServices/*.a', 'StaticLibraries/GoogleConversionTracking/*.a'
s.xcconfig = {'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-ObjC', 'CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES' => 'YES', 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2'}


arc_files = 'ProjectCore/**/ActionMenuHelper.{h,m}',
'ProjectCore/**/UnitsFormatter.{h,m}',
'ProjectCore/**/BSKeyboardControls/**/*.{h,m}',
'ProjectCore/**/CellMenuLeft.{h,m}',
'ProjectCore/**/CheckInternetConnection.{h,m}',
(...)

s.requires_arc = false
s.source_files = 'ProjectCore/**/*.{h,m,swift}','StaticLibraries/GoogleAnalyticsServices/*.h','StaticLibraries/GoogleConversionTracking/**/*.h','StaticLibraries/ZLib/*.h','StaticLibraries/XMLParser/*.h'

s.exclude_files = arc_files
s.subspec 'ARC' do |sp|
sp.requires_arc = true
sp.source_files = arc_files
end

s.resource_bundle  = { 'ProjectCore' => 'ProjectCore/**/*.{png,jpg,xib,strings}' }


s.dependency 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.11'
s.dependency 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.11'
s.dependency 'NSHash', '~> 1.1'
(...)

end
```

But my only error is this one:

```
- ERROR | [ProjectCore/ARC] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Creating your own CocoaPod is fairly straight forward. If you already
>   have a separate component, you're most of the way there. This guide is
>   an overview to the entire process, with the other guides in this
>   section serving as more of a deep-dive for more advanced users.

https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html

Comment: Thanks, I Check the guide deeply and after some testing there is an error in the build when I check $ pod lib lint. I'll edit the question.